# function sleep could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, sleep

I'm using eclipse and I'm building a simple program, but I get an error saying function sleep could not be resolved

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    printf("ciao");
    sleep(20);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if I need other libraries or something else.
MinGW should be installed properly, so I have no idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MinGW as stated, then you may need to include `windows.h`.  The sleep implementation I think uses the Win API `Sleep()`.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
    Sleep(20000);
    std::cout << "Text Will Appear After 2 Sec.." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `sleep()` function is defined by POSIX, not by the C++ standard.

If you're on a Unix-like system, you need

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

If you're not, then the `sleep()` function might not even be available.

Oh, and mixing `cout << ...` and `printf()` is probably not a good idea, and you don't need the `#include <conio.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

When developing portable code that must run on unix and windows, I've always defined a sleep() macro for windows that calls the windows Sleep() that looks like this:

```
#define sleep(a) Sleep(a * 1000)
```

It's simple enough to do.